# Разбивать таблицу на несколько или нет?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, sql-server, join

Вопрос в следующем.

Есть категория товаров, ее название и описание задается в админке.

Название категории самостоятельно, а вот описания зависит от города (мультимагазин, мультиязык).

Как лучше поступить: создать одну таблицу category_description с полями:

- category_id, name, description, language_id, city_id

Или же разбить ее на две таблицы?

1. category_description, где будет храниться поля category_id, name, language_id.
2. category_description_city, где будет храниться описания в зависимости от города: category_id, description, language_id, city_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, второй вариант, чтобы не дублировать в таблице категорий ничего. Это называется нормализация данных. Тут явная связь 1:N (1 категория - N городов). Вопрос еще в том, может ли существовать категория без городов вообще и может ли быть у нее описание по умолчанию?

Comment: Описание по умолчанию быть не может, если ее нет то отображается только название самой категории, без описания

Comment: Тогда второй вариант без всяких дополнений

Comment: Спасибо большое, а не подскажите как запросом вывести категорию если ее название в одной таблице а описание (если есть) в другой. LEFT JOIN возвращает пустой результат если нет описания...

Comment: покажите запрос тогда, именно LEFT JOIN обычно и решает такие задачи.

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "doctor_category dc LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "doctor_category_description dcd ON (dc.doctor_category_id = dcd.doctor_category_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "doctor_category_description_city dcdc ON (dc.doctor_category_id = dcdc.doctor_category_id)  WHERE dc.doctor_category_id = '" . (int)$doctor_category_id . "' AND dcd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND dcdc.city_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_city_id') . "'

Comment: нужно переместить условия по dcd и dcdc в соотвествующие блоки ON или дополнить эти условия OR'ом, примерно так (dcd.language_id=<config_languge_id> or dcd.language_id is null)